# Android app is not able to open some web pages?

Tags: android, android-webview

My android app is not able to open some web pages. The same url is working fine in a regular web browser. Thanks for your suggestions.

```
Error Msg: **Web Page not available**
The web page at www.talladega.edu might be temporarily down or
```

it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

```
**Here are some suggestions:**
 - Check signal and data connection
 - Reload this page later
 - View a cached copy of the web page from Google
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your time !

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
**@SuppressWarnings("static-access")**
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    pageLink  =  extras.getString("pageLink");
    if (pageLink != null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.displayview);
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);         
        web.enablePlatformNotifications();
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(pageLink);
        web.setWebViewClient(new localWebViewClient()); 
        //web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("silly_to_do_this");  --- **do I need to set this ?**
    }
}

private class localWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;            
    }
}
```

=== **displayview.xml** ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/pageBackGroundColor">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/pageBackGroundColor"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Regarding the comment: No, you don't need to use `setUserAgentString()`, it's just a string telling the server some information about the used software and OS on the client. The default one is fine. See [User agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Answer (score 0):

Does your application have permission to access the Internet?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, it was added above the 'application' tag in the manifest.

Comment: Some people say that it only works when it's put at the bottom just before the 'application' tag ends. Is that where you put it?

Comment: No It did'nt work when I put just before the 'application' tag ends. Then I'd put it above the 'application' tag starts and some pages started working !

Comment: ANY SUGGESTIONS/HELP GUYS? Is there any best alternate to open a website with out using WebView?